# How to write a program that calculates an average grade as a double-value which also shows the grade in a message box?

Tags: c#, button, average

I'm studying to become a Game Developer, and I use C#. Now one of the assignments is the following (it's translated from Dutch):

> Two students participate in a C#-exam. Their results (a whole number of points between 0 and 100) are assigned to two variables:
>
> ```
> int outcomeStudent1 = 44;
> int outcomeStudent2 = 51;
> ```
>
> Write a program that calculates the average grade as a `double`-value and shows this grade on screen. Check your answer with a calculator.

When I look a few pages further, the answers are there, which says:

> The values from a, b, c and d are respectively 5, 7, 12 and 8

This is what I put in my MainWindow.xaml:

- Two labels with the content:

  - Outcome Student 1
  - Outcome Student 2
- Two textboxes (which have been named in properties) so I can enter those values in there
- A button with the content Calculate grade

What I want to happen is:

- I enter the two values in the textboxes, and when I click the button, I want that message box to show me the average grade

This is my entire code so far (I've had only a tiny bit of help from a classmate because she wasn't at her laptop):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int outcomeStudent1 = 44;
        int outcomeStudent2 = 51;

        private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //outcomeStudent1 = 44
            //outcomeStudent2 = 51
            //Write a program that calculates the average grade as a double value

            double variable1;
            double variable2;
            variable1 = 44;
            variable2 = 51;

            int StudentA = 44;
            int StudentB = 51;
            double average;
            average = (double)StudentA + (double)StudentB / 2;

            //2*44=88
            //2*51=102
            //88+102=190
            //190/2=95
            
            MessageBox.Show("Average grade = " + average);
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm lost now, so what do I do to make this happen?

Comment: and what exactly does not work as you expect? What is your actual problem here, despite the fact that the formula for an average isn´t `x + y /2`, but `(x + y) / 2`.

Comment: Please provide the current and expected outcome: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to make this happen, I'm a first year student but my teacher barely explains anything, not even when we ask questions. I don't know how to be able to make sure that when I enter the values in the textboxes, and then click the button, that it calculates the average grade and shows it in a message box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the values from your User Interface first. To do this, you can access the values from the textboxes like shown below. Then convert the string values to integers.

After that calculate the average with (x + y) / 2 (your formula is wrong).
Then show the result in a messagebox.

The code below should work. Remember to create two textboxes in your xaml file, which are named `textbox1` and `textbox2` (maybe consider better naming later on)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int studentA = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text);
        int studentB = Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.Text);

        double average = (studentA + studentB) / 2.0;
        
        MessageBox.Show("Average grade = " + average);
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```